# Data type of expanding_apply output in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following function in python that outputs whether the sum of a series is even--

```
import pandas as pd
def sum_is_even(input):
    return((input.sum() % 2 == 0))
```

When run on a series, it outputs a boolean--

```
testSeries = pd.Series([1,2,3])
sum_is_even(testSeries)
```

Out[1]: True

When I apply it to the series using an expanding_apply, though, the output series ends up being a series of floats, not booleans--

```
pd.expanding_apply(testSeries, sum_is_even)
```

Out[841]: 
0    0.0
1    0.0
2    1.0
dtype: float64

Why is this?

Thanks!